# Constantly refreshing page instead of redirecting in PHP

Tags: php

Here is my server structure:

```
folder_in_root
another_folder/not_root_here
another_folder/nested_script.php
index.php                         #in root
one_script_in_root.php            #in root
```

I have the following function running in **ALL** the scripts of the server, whether in root or not:

```
function notify(){

   (...)

      if ( !(strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'index.php')) && ($feedback["connect_time"] == 0 || $feedback["http_code"] == 404)){
          exit("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0' ;url='../index.php'>");
    }


}
```

This function does not refresh the page if it is inside index.php, which is good, and heads to index.php if not inside index.php **WHEN** the original script is **NOT** on root. So, this script works in `another_folder/not_root_here`, `another_folder/not_root_here`, `index.php` but **FAILS** in `one_script_in_root.php` because it keeps  refreshing`one_script_in_root.php` over and over again instead of sending the user to `index.php`. I can't figure out why this happens. Can someone help me please? tyvm.

Comment: `'../index.php'` in root no need for `../`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This meta refresh has a wrong syntax

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=../index.php">
```

would be correct

Comment: ...which is the reason why it keeps on redirecting to itself in the absence of an URL.

Comment: @syck i think because the default url is the current so it redirect to the current one

Answer (score 1):

index.php is located at root of your domain, so just redirect to /

url="/"

Btw, you can use location header instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to just replace index.php with your domainname/ip. This makes the function work on whatever directory you call it.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=\\www.mydomain.com">
```